Does Hobbes believe that law is simply what an authority commands we ought to do?
I am currently reading about the differences between Spinoza and Hobbes on the subject of Divine Law, and I have a question about Hobbes’ views in this context.
Note that I am aware that both Spinoza and Hobbes predate the formal introduction of the idea of the Command Theory of Law. Therefore, my question is not about the specific term, instead, it is about the general ideas presented in the definition below.

The Command Theory of Law: the idea that law is simply what an authority commands we ought to do.

As I understand it, Spinoza rejects the Command Theory of Law (or common voluntarist perspective). Instead, Spinoza argues that laws are rooted in rationality and mutual interest, and he distinguishes between human law and Divine Law based on this principle.
Does Hobbes’ views align with the Command Theory of Law or does he offer a perspective that diverges from this theory? Additionally, does De Cive contain any passages or arguments that would confirm whether Hobbes adopts or aligns with the Command Theory of Law, particularly in relation to his understanding of natural and Divine Laws?

This is controversial and you will not get a clear answer. Hobbes is obscure and incoherent on the subject, possibly deliberately, see SEP, Hobbes’s Moral and Political Philosophy:"Most scholars have taken Hobbes to have affirmed some sort of personal relativism or subjectivism; but views that Hobbes espoused divine command theory, virtue ethics, rule egoism, or a form of projectivism also find support in Hobbes’s texts and among scholars."

Isn't Hobbes' argument that we need a sovereign authority for society to function and that you must surrender some of your rights to your sovereign and in turn the sovereign provides laws, protection, and security? I thought the "authority" (mentioned in the definition in my question) according to Hobbes' was simply the sovereign. @Conifold

The question is whether this sovereign is commanded by God or is simply a pragmatic human choice for self-preservation. "Although commentators do not agree on whether these laws should be regarded as mere precepts of prudence, or rather as divine commands, or moral imperatives of some other sort, all agree that Hobbes understands them to direct people to submit to political authority" SEP. Hobbes is clear on what humans should do, not why.

So to clarify: 1) it is clear that Hobbes does believe in The Command Theory of Law (as defined in the question). 2) The controversial matter is that we don't know what Hobbes would consider the authority to be. Is my understanding right? @Conifold

I do not think your formulation reflects Hobbes, he is not either or. He derives "absolute authority" from something else (what exactly is controversial, 'laws of nature', divine commands, prudence, etc.), based on that he reserves to its subjects some 'inalienable' rights of disobedience (how that coheres with "absolutism" of authority, if at all, is also controversial). So what the authority commands is not "simply the law". Apparently, it is constrained by its purpose and 'inalienable' rights, and its commands are the law only as long as it serves that purpose without infringing on them.

It would be great if you could write this up in more detail in an answer to clarify if possible @Conifold

SEP already did a better job than what can be done here.
